# Why does InRange(TColor lower, TColor higher) return the wrong "value"?

Tags: emgucv

As you can see in http://snag.gy/wVqG4.jpg Inrange(0,0,0,255,255,255) does not return a completely white image and so it does not properly check if all colors are in range. What is wrong? 
 Full source: https://mega.co.nz/#!s4BXzKja!SpLk2z9NI8V-fIZTK8oyT15lh-ZRj6HhJ1f61wxc358

Comment: It works well for me. Could you upload the original image and indicate how you load the image: Image<Bgra, byte> ?

Comment: @rold2007 Image<Bgr, Byte> and I will edit my post with full source included. It's only a test after all.

Comment: Intead of giving me your full source code, you should create a small example which reproduces your problem. StackOverflow is not a debugging service. Anyways, I tried your code and the image I tried was completely white in Color_wizard. But I noticed your sliders sometimes stop around 1 or 254 instead of 0 and 255, so it might only be a usability issue with your UI.

Comment: Please try a few images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem with your version of EmguCV (2.2.1.1150) but not with mine (2.4.2.1777)

The problem you see is caused by a change of behavior in OpenCV between version 2.2.0 and 2.3.0. In version 2.2.0 the upper bound was excluded 'low <= value < high' while in 2.3.0 and higher it is 'low <= value <= high'. Upgrade your version of EmguCV if you want the later behavior.

As a workaround you can also map your slider maximum position to "value+1", if you only work with integer values.

This problem was already reported here: http://code.opencv.org/issues/1500

Comment: In my defense: for some reason I didn't find this bugreport.